# Noise complaint about a neighbor who is excessively loud during the day with his subwoofer

Tags: united-states, noise, lease

I'm a student and when I'm not in school, I study at home (I live in Boston, USA). Often, 2-3 times a week, the neighbor who lives 1 floor below me starts playing video-games / watching movies at high volume in the afternoon or evening hours. I have noise-cancelling headphones, and for the most part they are life-savior, except this case – because the neighbor has subwoofer speakers and I literally feel with my feet how the floor (and furniture) shakes because of loud sounds, and it seriously distracts me from my study.

I have a lease agreement which says that noise is prohibited after 10pm, but there is no clause that any noise during the day. Can I still submit a formal complaint to my landlord about this neighbor? Or should I just call non-emergency police during each noise incident?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[These](https://www.boston.gov/departments/environment/rules-noise-boston) are the limits in Boston: 50 decibels from 11 p.m. to 7 a.m. and 70 decibels at any time. If it is annoying you then it is *probably* greater than 70 dB, you can buy a sound meter if you want to be sure. The advice is:

> **Car alarms, loud parties, or loud amps:** Call the Boston Police Party Line at 617-343-5500, or contact your local police station.